# How do I toggle the display of divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, toggle

I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/eu30mcps/ , but it does not work. How can I display the first `div`, when I click on the first button... and so on?

```js
function DisplayKat1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("kat1");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function DisplayKat2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("kat2");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function DisplayKat3() {
  var x = document.getElementById("kat3");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
    <button class="btn default" onklick="DisplayKat1()">A</button>
    <button class="btn default" onklick="DisplayKat2()">B</button>
    <button class="btn default" onklick="DisplayKat3()">C</button>
</p>


<div id="kat1">
    Text A
</div>

<div id="kat2">
    Text B
</div>

<div id="kat3">
    Text C
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise a bit simpler approach.
Define new css class called `hidden`:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Have only one function that appends `hidden` class to each of your `kat`s (get the id of kat from the event handlers).

```
function hideKat(katId) {
 var kat = document.getElementById(katId);
 kat.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

Replace your onclick handlers with the new one:

```
<p>
<button class="btn default" onclick="hideKat('kat1')">A</button>
<button class="btn default" onclick="hideKat('kat2')">B</button>
<button class="btn default" onclick="hideKat('kat3')">C</button>
</p>


<div id="kat1">
Text A
</div>

<div id="kat2">
Text B
</div>

<div id="kat3">
Text C
</div>
```

**PS:** you had a typo in your buttons: `onklick` -> `onclick`

Comment: Glad to help, keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you just need to change your HTML structure. Add a `data-target` indicating the divs `id` value. Here it is-

```js
const btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')];

btns.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const div = document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.target);
    if (div) {
      if (div.style.display === 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#kat1,
#kat2,
#kat3 {
  display: none;
  /* You can make the display block initially. It's up to you */
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="btn default" data-target="#kat1">A</button>
  <button class="btn default" data-target="#kat2">B</button>
  <button class="btn default" data-target="#kat3">C</button>
</p>


<div id="kat1">Text A</div>
<div id="kat2">Text B</div>
<div id="kat3">Text C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no event called klick, you probably meant onclick.